# How to make parts of texture shiny and reflective?

Tags: texturing, materials

Basically, I'm making a matte object with no highlights, and only some parts of it are covered with metallic paint that should be glossy and reflective.

Hopefully this explains what I mean:

[image]

I'm using Blender Internal render.

The "desired effect" part has Wardiso specular and a bit of reflection.

I have a specular map on the column body (blue parts are black and golden parts are very light grey), in the Textures tab it's set up like this:

[image]

I've tried bringing up the Specular in the Material tab (it's currently at 0), but it affects the parts that are black on the specular map as well. It's my first time using specular maps, did I not set it up correctly?

Anyway, is it possible to achieve the desired effect without having to separate the mesh?

UPD: Golden parts are much more shiny now. I only need to make them more reflective to imitate metallic paint properly.

Comment: So you already have 2 (or more) different materials? A metallic and a non-metallic one?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The "desired effect" part and the column part share two textures - diffuse color and specular - but the former is a different material. I understand this might be not the proper way to do it, but I'm new to Blender and this is the best I could come up with on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For demonstration purpose, the specular map is also being used as the diffuse channel to showcase the effect more.

Normally, the diffuse color map should only have the 'Diffuse Color' checked in the influence tab and the specular map shouldn't have this one checked at all.

Without the specular map influence:

[image: No influence render]

[image: No influence tab]

With the specular map influencing the material's specular behavior:
[image: With influence render]
[image: With influence tab]

Reflectivity:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've played with Specular influence of the diffuse color texture, and the golden parts look much shinier now. This only leaves the reflection - is it possible to map a texture that would determine which parts are reflective and which aren't?

Comment: When talking about reflection and the blender internal render engine, you have to check the 'mirror' option in the material tab and in the texture influence map. Blender internal is not very good at realistic reflection tough... You should be using Cycles for a more realistic approach!

Comment: It's okay if it's not realistic! I've tried checking Mirror in the influence tab - just the diffuse color map, just the specular map, and them both, but the blue parts are still affected. Do I have to switch to Cycles after all?

Comment: You have to check the mirror influence only on the specular map, but als in your material settings.

Comment: Let me just update my post real quick...

Comment: Thank you, I've finally figured it out! Turned out I messed up the blend mode of the texture itself, that's why it behaved in a way I didn't want. Thanks to your advice, it's looking much better now!